# Converting .gri to topojson

Tags: convert, elevation, file-formats, topography, topojson

I am making client-end javascript-powered maps in the context of web development. I am not using gdal, which I gather is a special kind of rendering software.

Data source site: http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata

Previously, I was able to download the shapefile of my country of interest and its administrative regions. Client maps need to be small of course due to data transfer, so I found information on how to convert shapefiles to geojson and then topojson and finally how to simplify. All that worked like a charm.

The troubles began when I looked to find a way to convert/resample .gri files containing elevation data to topojson. Again, this data is from diva-gis. As it stands, the .gri format is not recognizable to my javscript mapping libraries and it's still large in file size.

### Question

Is it possible to convert and simplify an elevation data file for a country in .gri format? If so how? If not, is there another convention for obtaining elevation/topographic data in a small-sized topojson?

**Software I must use (no gdal)**

- javscript (d3,topojson)
- node